# PowerShell Convertto-HTML add data to column

Tags: html, powershell, scripting, powershell-2.0

I have this script

```
$a = "<style>"
$a = $a + "TABLE{border-width: 1px;border-style: solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "Table{background-color:#ffffff;border-collapse: collapse;}"
$a = $a + "TH{border-width:1px;padding:0px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "TR{border-width:1px;padding-left:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "TD{border-width:1px;padding-left:5px;border-style:solid;border-color:black;}"
$a = $a + "</style>"


dir -path  "\\server\loctation$"  |where {$_.mode -match "d"} | select-object  name, creationtime, lastwritetime, Owner| ConvertTo-Html -head $a | Out-File "\\server\location\drivelistings.html"
```

It outputs the results fine.

But I want to add a column to the end of the table which has prefixed data in.

Currently page outputs:

```
   Name   Creation Time    LateWriteTime   Owner
   Test   2013/04/12       2013/04/12
   Test2  2013/04/12       2013/04/12
   Test3  2013/04/12       2013/04/12
```

I want to use the member column to manually type in the owner. This data will not change and neither will the folder structure.

For example:

```
   Name   Creation Time    LateWriteTime   Owner
   Test   2013/04/12       2013/04/12      user1
   Test2  2013/04/12       2013/04/12      user2
   Test3  2013/04/12       2013/04/12      user3
```

Any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can create a csv the maps the owner to the foldername, fullpath or something unique, you can try this:

folder-user-mappings.csv

```
"FolderName","Owner"
"Test","user1"
"Test2","user2"
"Test3","user3"
```

Script

```
$a = Import-Csv folder-user-mappings.csv
#Convert to hashtable to simplify code and search faster
$mappings = @{}
$a | % { $mappings.Add($_.FolderName, $_.Owner) }

dir -path  "\\server\loctation$" | 
where {$_.mode -match "d"} |
select-object name, creationtime, lastwritetime, @{n="Owner";e={$mappings[$_.Name]}} | 
ConvertTo-Html -head $a | 
Out-File "\\server\location\drivelistings.html"
```

Comment: I will give that a try :) never thought of that!